# Substring macro parameter

Tags: c, macros

It is possible to substring somehow a macro parameter?
I am facing the following problem. I have something like

```
#define READ(Name) structure.##Name.value
```

This macro will be called with something like PREFIX_Name and in the structure there are names without the PREFIX. So I need to take care of that prefix. How should I do that?

Comment: So, you want `READ(PREFIX_abc)` to expand to `structure.abc.value`? Is this existing code, or you are doing this for no particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is obviously not to call the macro like that. The second best option is to rename the struct members.

Failing the good options, the least bad option I can come up with is to write a macro per structure member:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x; int y;} foo;

#define PREFIX_x_FIXER structure.x
#define PREFIX_y_FIXER structure.y

#define READ(Name) Name##_FIXER

int main (void)
{
  foo structure;
  READ(PREFIX_x) = 5;
  printf("%d\n", READ(PREFIX_x));
}
```